# 2 updates within one Firestore transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore transaction, and would like to update a document field based the current data of the document.

My planned transaction is given below:

```
const cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
try {
    await db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
        const doc = await t.get(cityRef);
        let status = doc.data().myStatus;

        if (status == "one") {
            throw "err";
        } else {

            // run some function - next status is based on the return             
            let output = await someFunction();

            if (output) {
                await t.update(cityRef, { myStatus: "two" });
                return output;
            } else {
                await t.update(cityRef, { myStatus: "three" });
                return output;
            }
        }
    });
    console.log("transaction successful");

} catch (err) {
    console.log("Alreadu updated");
    output = "one";
    return output;
}
```

My queries are given below:

1. As per the documentation I have returned the data after `update`, however it does not seem to be working as expected.
2. Can we have 2 updates within one single transaction (both are updating the same field in the firestore)?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by " it does not seem to be working as expected." Can you share a snippet of the output? Also, why are you updating to the same value, myStatus: two, in both scenarios?

Comment: Why do you do `db.collection('cities').doc('SF');` on one hand and `app.db.runTransaction` on the other hand? What is `app`, you should do `db.runTransaction`? Also, what is `someFunction()`? Does it treats/reads docs outside of the transaction? This will not work.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Apologies, I have updated the question. `db.collection('cities').doc('SF');` should have been outside the transaction.

Comment: @Hydra I have just updated the question. 
Based on the output from the `someFunction()` I need to set the value of the `myStatus`. 
`myStatus` was initially set to `one`, and if the `someFunction()` returns `true` then we set the `myStatus` to `two`, else to `three`.

Comment: @KK2491 I still don't understand why you use `db` in `db.collection('cities').doc('SF');` and `app.db` in `app.db.runTransaction`. `runTransaction()` is a method of the Firestore service interface like `collection()` is. Why two different ways for defining Firestore? Also, we need to know what does `someFunction()` do, in order to help you. And also any error you get?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Sorry for that. I have updated the question. 
`someFunction()` does some processing on other firestore collection/documents (not the one I am updating) and returns either `true` or `false`. 
Based on the output of the `someFunction()` I update the new value for the document field as either `two` or `three`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make the following clarification in the comments above:

> `someFunction()` does some processing on other firestore
> collection/documents (not the one I am updating) and returns either
> true or false.

As you read in the doc on Transactions, "Read operations must come before write operations". If you want to read some docs in the transaction, you need to use the `get()` method of the Transaction, like you did with the first document. You cannot call a function that is using other Firestore methods like the `get()` method of a `DocumentReference`.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. 
If I am understanding correctly, I can not call a function that is modifying / using Firestore methods on the same document field. 
In my case `someFunction()` does have the `get()` Firestore function, however it is not on the same document which is being updated within the transaction.

Comment: You need to include these doc(s) in the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I misunderstood the documentation, I was thinking we can do normal `get()` operations on documents/collections which are not being updated in transaction using `t.update()` function.